# Combining three tables when two have the same foreign key

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

Hello I am making some accounting software that allows you to store transactions across many months (stored in table `transactions`) and categorize those transactions based on a list of available categories (stored in table `categories`).  Finally each month the user can create a budget where they build a list (from a subset of `categories`) and assign a goal to each entry.  These lists are stored in table `budget`.

[image: Table Relationship]

I need a query that returns a spending and budget summary for a specified month. This summary would be a table of categories.name, budget.goal, and sum(transactions.amount).

[image: Expected Result]

Sometimes a user would have a budget item for the specified month but hasn't made any transactions with that category yet (Out to Eat example).  Sometimes a user would have an unexpected expense they didn't budget for (Auto Repair Example) and there will be some categories (like vacation) where the user didn't budget that item and there were no expenses of that category.

`SELECT categories.id, categories.name, SUM(transactions.amount) 
FROM categories 
LEFT JOIN transactions ON categories.id=transactions.category_id 
WHERE transactions.date LIKE '2019-08-%' GROUP BY categories.id;`

gets me half of what I want and

`SELECT categories.id, categories.name, budgets.goal 
FROM categories 
LEFT JOIN budgets ON categories.id=budgets.category_id 
WHERE budgets.date LIKE '2019-08-%' GROUP BY categories.id;`

gets me the other half of what I want.  Is there a single query that can return results like what I have pictured above?  I would be even more thrilled if we could exclude results where both goal and sum are NULL.

Comment: Can there be multiple butgets from the same month for the same category?

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that there can be at most one budget per category and month, then you can (LEFT) JOIN both (child) tables to `categories`:

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  categories.name,
  MAX(b.goal) as budget_goal,
  SUM(t.amount) as total_txn_amount
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN budgets b
  ON  c.id = b.category_id 
  AND b.date LIKE '2019-08-%'
LEFT JOIN transactions t
  ON c.id = t.category_id 
GROUP BY categories.id
HAVING COALESCE(budget_goal, total_txn_amount) IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that while we know that there can be only one budget per group, the engine doesn't, and might claim that `b.goal` must be either in the GROUP BY clause or used in an aggregate function. So we use `MAX(b.goal)` to avoid that error.

To improve the performance of the first JOIN I would change

```
AND b.date LIKE '2019-08-%'
```

to

```
AND b.date >= '2019-08-01'
AND b.date <  '2019-08-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

and create a composite index on `(category_id, date)`.

Also to force the uniqueness of category and month combination in the `budgets` table, I would create a virtual column like

```
year_month VARCHAR(7) as (LEFT(date, 7))
```

and a UNIQUE KEY on `(category_id, year_month)`

Then you can use

```
LEFT JOIN budgets b
  ON  c.id = b.category_id 
  AND b.date = '2019-08'
```

Comment: That works perfectly thank you.  I was having a terrible time joining two tables to the same primary key.  I don't know what I was omitting but I kept getting errors and all the online examples showed joining "c to b then b to a" and so forth.  I was afraid this wasn't possible.  Well done and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query to find the proper result :

```
SELECT c.name,b.goal,sum(ct.amount) FROM era.categories c left join budget b on b.cat_id=c.id left join transactions ct on ct.cat_id=c.id WHERE b.date LIKE '2019-08-%' group by ct.cat_id;
```

Thanks.